# style.php prints plain text rather than displaying css

Tags: php, css

I am passing common css color value to style.php. but after closing php tag. when it comes to actual css rules then it display plain text rather than css.

**Style.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$common_color : "#888888";

?>

body{
color : <?php echo "$common_color" ?>;
}

h1{
color : <?php echo "$common_color" ?>;
}
```

How can I solve it?

I am referring [this link](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)

Comment: How does it display the plain text? How are you calling up your stylesheet? If you just run this php file in your browser, it will display the content, yes; just like an ordinary .css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
$common_color = "#888888";

?>
<style type="text/css">
  body{
  color : <?php echo "$common_color" ?>;
  }

  h1{
  color : <?php echo "$common_color" ?>;
  }

</style>
```

in your **style.php** wrap your **CSS** in `style` tag.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do as mentioned below

```
<?php
$common_color = "#888888";

?>
<style type="text/css">
body{
color : <?php echo $common_color ?>;
}

h1{
color : <?php echo $common_color ?>;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have changed 
$common_color : "#888888";
to 
$common_color = "#888888";

Comment: Yes I have removed.

Comment: what is the name of your page.
If style.php then it's working properly. Is there any thing else in your page ?

Comment: Also add style tag before body tag and close after h1 tag 
<style>
body{
color : <?php echo $common_color ?>;
}

h1{
color : <?php echo $common_color ?>;
}
</style>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152442/discussion-between-priyank-and-rishi).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$common_color = "#888888";
```

Comment: i didn't noticed from copy pasting that it's that ":" there. I mean $common_color = "#888888" , of course

Comment: have you used <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?> on the top of your file?

Answer (score 0):

`$common_color` is a PHP variable so you don't need to add double quotes. Just remove those quotes:

```
<?php
$common_color = "#888888";

?>

body {
    color: <?php echo $common_color; ?>;
    }
h1 {
    color: <?php echo $common_color; ?>;
}
```

**Output:**

```
body{ color : '#888888'; } h1{ color : '#888888'; }
```

Working demo. Ensure its inside `<style>` tag:

```
<?php
$common_color = "#d00";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                color: <?php echo $common_color; ?>;
            }
            h1{
                color: <?php echo $common_color; ?>;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            some text
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @MilanChheda I'm being pedantic, but you can actually have variable names inside double quotes in PHP. `echo $var;` outputs exactly the same thing as `echo "$var";`

Answer (score 0):

You have create a php page with name of "style.php" that content some css code.You need to include this file in in html as in other html/php file 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inter.php">`

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php">
</head>
```

If you want  to use as php variable then you have to remove the header `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");` from top of style.php file. Because header content type convert the output into css. So after closing php tag output would be as text.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$common_color = "#888888";

?>

body{
color : '<?php echo $common_color; ?>';
}

h1{
color : '<?php echo $common_color; ?>';
}
```

Try this, you need apostrophe

Comment: No you don't. Your answer will only make it worse.